# Online service to execute Ruby scripts

Tags: monitoring, ruby, amazon-web-services, cloud, remote-execution

I am investigating the possibility to start a backup up server remotely in case the main server fails. The idea is:

1. Amazon Route 53 monitors the main server
2. The server fails, which triggers an alarm in Cloud Watch
3. Cloud Watch pushes a new Simple Message Nofication
4. The SNS sends a HTTP/S request somewhere which triggers execution of a Ruby script
5. The script spins off a new instance somewhere in the cloud (but not in AWS)

Is there a service available online which triggered by a HTTP/S request would execute an arbitrary Ruby script?

The service would work in a similar way to [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com), only it would execute a script instead of sending a SMS or making a call.

Comment: You rely on amazon route 53, but don't trust AWS enough to spin new instance in AWS?  (anyway, it sounds like you want the ruby equiv of pythonanywhere.com ?)

Comment: AWS doesn't support FreeBSD (or I should add "properly"). Not a fault on the AWS side. Yes, pythonanywhere.com sounds like it, if only it was Ruby and allowed me to trigger the execution of that script with a POST request.